# SFML - texture doesn't change correctly

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm writing a program using SFML. I have a graph class and I have a node class. What I want to do is changing texture of a node when user clicks LMB on it. I did it and that's rather ok. But, if there was another node already "clicked", when user clicks on some other node, we should change texture of that first node to "not-clicked". I did it, too. But it doesn't work 100% correct. The texture of the first node doesn't change right after we click on another node (and it should), but when we move mouse or click once more somewhere. It seems that it takes one more iteration of for loop to change that texture and that's why texture of the first node doesn't change right after we click on another node. I tried to fix it by adding another for loop or by switching some pieces of code to another place, but with no luck.

Here's my entire Update() method of Graph class.

```
void Graf::Update(RenderWindow &win, GameObject &gm, Event &ev) {
    for (int i=0; i<rozmiar; i++) { //begin loop
        if (gm.KlikniecieMyszka(w[i].getSpr(), win, ev)) { //if there was a mouse click
            for (int j=0; j<rozmiar; j++) { //check if we have a node that already has a "clicked" texture, that is "tagged"
                if (w[j].zaznaczony) { w[j].zaznaczony=false; break; } //and if so, change value of "zaznaczony" (that means "tagged") to false, so we can switch its texture to the appropiate one. and break that for loop, because there can be only one already "tagged" node
            }
            if (!w[i].odwiedzony) w[i].odwiedzony=true; //so, if the node that user just clicked on wasn't yet "visited" ("odwiedzony"), change value of "odwiedzony" ("visited") to true

            w[i].zaznaczony=true; //and set "zaznaczony" ("tagged") to true, so the program knows that this is our currently clicked node
            dzwiek_nn.play(); //and play some sound
        }
            //now, changing textures
        if (w[i].zaznaczony) //tagged node
            w[i].aktualna_tex=ZAZNACZONY; //change its texture to TAGGED
        else { //not currently tagged node
            if (w[i].odwiedzony) //but if it was already visited
                w[i].aktualna_tex=ODWIEDZONY; //change its texture to VISITED
            else
                w[i].aktualna_tex=NIEODWIEDZONY; //change its texture to NOTVISITED
        }
        w[i].Update(win, gm, ev); //and update node. this method just changes the texture of the node (node.setTexture - that's all)
    }
}
```

Comment: To be honest, to somebody speaking english, your code looks like random gibberish. If you format it properly and use english names, you may generate better responses. You may also want to include a sentence about what exactly your `w` array is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time following the state of this function.  I find that when I need to write complicated code that could have many states, I write out a flow-chart.

Right now it looks like your nodes can have any of the three state: current, visited, not visited.  I seriously suggest you get a piece of paper and draw it out.  Also, I recommend being consistent with bracket and line-space use, especially if you're looking for help.